# Map through an object with children objects- Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to map through an object "contentMap"(which is inside an array "faqArray") and access "question" and "answer" which are inside objects "policy1", "policy2" etc.

Below is my sample json data.

```
"faqArray": [{
    "contentMap": {
      "policy1": {
        "answer": "Cookies are small text files.",
        "question": "<strong>What are Cookies?</strong>"
      },
      "policy2": {
        "answer": "Please call the number.",
        "question": "<strong>How do I contact by phone?</strong>"
      },
      "policy3": {
        "answer": "bla bla",
        "question": "<strong>What is bla?</strong>"
      },
    },
    "header": ""
  },

]
```

Below is react component level code that is trying to access question and answer.

```
{faqArray.map((faqInfoGroup, i) => [
    <div key={i}>
      <div className="faqQuestionGroup" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(faqInfoGroup.header)}></div>
        {Object.keys(faqInfoGroup).map((qaMap, i) =>
          <div className="faqQuestions" key={i}>
            Q.&nbsp; <a className="faqLinks" href={`#default_${qaMap.question}`} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup(qaMap.question)}>  
            </a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
])}
```

Using the code above, I am able to map through "faqArray" using .map. I am also able to map through the object "contentMap" using Object.keys(faqInfoGroup).map.
But my real problem is accessing question and answer inside policy1, policy2 and policy3.
Object.keys(faqInfoGroup).map gives me "policy1", "policy2" etc. as strings rather than objects. Because of this, policy1.answer, policy.question doesn't work.

I tried javascript forEach() as well, but the still unable to access question and answer.

How can I access "question" and "answer" that are inside "policy1", policy2" and policy3" ?

Please let me know your suggestions. It would be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `faqInfoGroup.contentMap[qaMap].question` (after @abhi's comment)

```
{faqArray.map((faqInfoGroup, i) => [
    {Object.keys(faqInfoGroup).map((qaMap, i) => {
        //faqInfoGroup.contentMap[qaMap].question
        //faqInfoGroup.contentMap[qaMap].answer
    })}
])}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhiraj. It worked after some modification. faqArray[i].contentMap[qaMap].question wasn't working, so I did faqInfoGroup.contentMap[qaMap].question.